# How to add tabs in a IONIC 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to add two simple tabs in a ionic 2 app, but I'm encountering some troubles due to the fact that I'm new to AngularJs and ionic 2. I read around the Ionic documentation and googled around but I think I'm missing something. I can't show my tabs. Here below the codes I have right now:

**HOME.TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs'
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    tabs: any;
    socket: any;
    chat_input: string;
    chats = [];
    prova = [];
    photoValue = [];
    rangeSettings: number;
    slideValueBadge = [];
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
        this.socket = io('http://192.168.1.21:3000');
        this.socket.on('photo', (value) => {
            //Debug purpose
            //console.log("Luminosità: ", value);
            this.photoValue.push(value);
        });
        this.tabs = TabsPage;
    }
//SOME OTHER CODES
}
```

**TABS.TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { ServerSetts } from '../home/serverSetts';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
    tab1Root: any = HomePage;
    tab2Root: any = ServerSetts;


    constructor() {

    }
}
```

**SERVERSETTS.TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'serverSetts.html'
})
export class ServerSetts {
   constructor() {}
}
```

**APP.MODULE.TS**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ServerSetts } from '../pages/home/serverSetts';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/home/tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
      HomePage,
      ServerSetts,
      TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
      HomePage,
      ServerSetts,
      TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

of course I have an *tabs.html*, *serverSetts.html* and an *home.html*.
The app is loading and works great but no tabs are shown. Any help please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your code sample by templates used in TabsPage component.  Basic tabs usage should be pretty straightforward following [official Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/).

Try moving your tabs html tags inside some main Ionic tags, e.g. `<ion-content></ion-content>` or `<ion-header></ion-header>`.

As a side note I would suggest using ng-socket-io plugin for angular2 that nicely fits into angular's architecture and allows you to retrieve data in service and subscribe to it from components. You can find example of this design pattern [in official ng-socket-io repository](https://github.com/bougarfaoui/ng-socket-io)